# Creating Photosharing app on Android

Tags: android, google-app-engine, instagram, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-messaging

I want to develop android application like **Photofeed** application as mentioned on [Google cloud sample](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/photofeed/overview) link or like Instagram. For that I need `App Engine SDK` but i am not getting how i will achieve this functionality. In my app, i want exact functionalities (uploading image, like and comment on that photo) like `Photofeed` app shown on that link. For that I'll have to use `Google Cloud Storage` but `Photofeed` is for Webapp and i want to develop Mobile app. For that i also referred [Mobile back-end starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/) but not getting much idea. Its quite confusing. Please guide me to develop this application. Is it possible to use `Photofeed sample` java classes in my android application?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/) and make Android Connected App Engine Application. [This is a good starting point](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae).

You can make similar app or any app that connects to GAE as backend in 4 steps as follows:

1. **Make your entity classes**: You can use JPA, JDO or [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) to access the Data Store or use its [API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) directly as done in the sample NoSQL classes (The easiest way is Objectify IMO). Or you can use Google Cloud SQL as done in the SQL classes of the sample ( I never used that in a project so I do not know if there is another way beside the [API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/)).
2. **Make REST Endpoints**: You can use [Google Cloud Endpoints](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) to make REST API for your own app. This will allow you to develop Android, iOS and JavaScript clients in unified way. If needed you can secure it using OAuth too.
3. **Generate Client Libraries**: If you are using Eclipse, Google Plugin will provide that in the context menu of the App Engine project so you simply right click and click Generate Client Libraries. It can be done using [command line](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients) too.
4. **Consume the endpoints in the Android app**: This is done really simple as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android).

**Note** : You will need a Servlet to upload photos to Google Cloud Storage. You can make use of [the one in the sample](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-solutions/source/browse/trunk/photo-sharing-demo/src/com/google/cloud/demo/UploadHandlerServlet.java).

Comment: I thought of using https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/photofeed/overview application and then i'll create REST endpoints for that app and then perform your steps-2,3,4 for my mobile backend support. Am i right? Please reply.

Comment: Yes it can be done this way. You can make the extra REST layer that uses the existing classes of the sample to save and query. But honestly I think it will not save you much time because Objectify allows you to make your entities really easy and fast. So it will be more clean to use Objectify IMO.

Comment: Actually i want to use Cloud storage and that's why i am going for Google Cloud SQl.

Comment: They are not related. In GAE there two options for storing data: The Data Store and Google Cloud SQL. The first is non-relational the second is relational. There are two options for storing files/blobs too: the Blob Store and Google Gloud Storage. You can free to use any without requiring to use another.